# "Getting hourly data for NYC in R using rnoaa/countyweather packages"

Tags: r, api, latitude-longitude, weather, rnoaa

I am trying to get hourly weather data for New York City from NOAA by using rnoaa and countyweather packages. I'm trying to do some version of the Kaggle Capital Bikeshare Demand Prediction problem and I need HOURLY precipitation, windspeed and relative humidity data for 2016-2017.

I'm running the function "hourly_fips", but keep getting an error and I can't seem to figure out why.

I've been trying to run the examples in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/countyweather/vignettes/countyweather.html , but can't get it to work.

This is the example I've been running. This is supposed to get hourly temperature data for Miami-Dade county.

```
ex <- hourly_fips("12086", coverage = 0.90, year = c(1994, 1995),
                  var = "temperature")
```

I'm hoping to use the same function to find the same kind of data for New York City.

The error I'm getting is

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'longitude' not found
```

which is confusing because the function doesn't ask for a longitude argument.

Comment: I think it occur because of loading the 1994 and 1995 data. Call it up individually and bind it.

Comment: `rnoaa` maintainer here, did you figure this out yet?